# Webcam images on HP Envy 15 are all purple

Tags: webcam

I have a new HP Envy 15 with an integrated webcam, running Win 7.  It works, but all the images are purple, suggesting to me that the red and blue guns are working, but the green isn't. The problem shows up on both their own software and on Skype.

I talked to tech support, and they had me update the BIOS, reinstall the hardware BIOS for the webcam, and update the webcam software.  It therefore sounds like a hardware problem, but they won't back that unless I do a full restore, which would wipe my disk of all the software I've spent the last couple of weeks configuring.

Is there anything else I can try? Other than just buying another webcam, I mean.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not that I'm advocating dishonesty, but if I *know* something is a hardware problem, I usually just tell them what they want to hear re: wiping, etc.

Comment: /agreed - asking the customer to blow away their entire machine is ridiculous. Cue the story about the technician that would not support an install wtih *any* changes made to it...

Answer (score 2):

Try booting the machine with a live linux CD that supports webcams, perhaps Ubuntu does, that way you can rule out the OS. If you can't do that any have access to another disk you could remove the existing disk, pop in a temporary one, put a new OS build on it and see if it's still a problem.